# Code crashes in memcpy due to faulty pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

For some reason I can't understand the following code crashes (without any error message; gcc 7.4.0 Ubuntu 16.04, QT5) at the second `memcpy` in the loop so I am guessing  that my pointer arithmetic is wrong but I don't understand why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 48
#define COLS 48
#define CHANNELS 3
#define NUM_PIX ((ROWS) * (COLS) * (CHANNELS))
struct MyImage
{
  int width;
  int height;
  int channels;
  unsigned char rawData[NUM_PIX];
};

int main()
{
  const int numIm = 16;
  MyImage theClsImArr[numIm];
  unsigned char ImArr[numIm][ROWS][COLS][CHANNELS];
  int Bytes2Copy = NUM_PIX * sizeof(unsigned char);
  for (int i = 0; i < numIm; i++ )
     memcpy(theClsImArr[i].rawData,ImArr + i * NUM_PIX ,Bytes2Copy ); // works when i = 0, crashes at i = 1

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ImArr + i * NUM_PIX` is undefined behavior if `i * NUM_PIX > CHANNELS`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik , Why? isn't `ImArr` just an address? can't I add it some value?

Comment: No, you can't http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4

Comment: Side note: `sizeof(unsigned char)` is always 1. Also, storing large arrays as local variables can cause stack overflows.

Comment: What is `CHANNELS` defined as? I only see a definition of `CAHNNELS`.

Comment: Why not simply `memcpy(theClsImArr[i].rawData,ImArr[i] ,Bytes2Copy );`

Comment: Also: In C++, variable length arrays as shown are non standard and only supported by some compilers as an extension.

Comment: Is this a C or C++ quesiton? Please only tag with the relevant language

Comment: @Michael - My mistake, there is only `CHANNELS`

Comment: @Erlkoenig - where do you see variable length arrays?

Comment: @ikegami - the fragment is taken from C++ code but it's relevant for C also.

Comment: Your code is missing an include.

Comment: @ikegami No. `const int`, together with a constant expression initialiser, has been a valid compile-time constant in C++ since at least C++03, possibly longer.

Comment: @BennyK Nevertheless the two are distinct langauges *with different rules* regarding pointers, so questions should be about one or the other, not both. If you are interested in both, please ask two distinct questions.

Comment: @LPs OP has said that the code is C++, the `struct` qualifier is therefore unnecessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok, you corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ImArr+i` instead of `ImArr + i * NUM_PIX`. The addition will automatically factor in the size of the array element, which is equal to a whole image block.